# One form by row (fields for every column) with buttons for each: how to manage the dirty state?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I would like to handle the dirty state for every single row I have in my table. Unfortunately, adding a form around a  would break the table, and I can't create it inside since I have a field for every different column. My last column for each row contains buttons: Delete and Update. Update appears only if one of the field of this row has been made dirty.

Somehow, it works already but I am checking each .pristine for every field on that row (`#name="ngModel"`). My rows are created through something like `*ngFor="let row of rows"`. I believe it would be better to check the `.dirty` or `.pristine` on a form rather than on every single element.

Also, if I actually to the update, there is no way I can remove that .dirty status (I tried replacing the data for that row by removing from the array and re-adding it but it is still dirty).

Is there a technique to go around that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ngModelGroup around each of your rows. Then you can check the dirty flag for the group.

Comment: So you mean a form for the whole table, then a ngModelGroup per row?

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this then. I am surprized I can't see any examples or articles about having a table and dynamic forms in it; I almost wondered if I am doing it right or if I should do it in a totally different way.

Comment: Actually I don't think it's possible to do what I need with a ngModelGroup on every row. How can I handle an Update on every row with it? The Update will not be able to submit the content of the ngModelGroup since it has to be linked to the whole form. I can handle the button manually but then there is no way I can change the .dirty value of the ngModelGroup...

Comment: If you could provide a plunker demonstrating a scaled down version of what you are trying to do, we may be able to help further.